# Logging results to an excel file (apache poi), error if I open the file while program is still running

Tags: java, save, apache-poi, readonly, filenotfoundexception

I have a program that does various tasks and then logs the results to an excel file. I'm using Apache POI.

The program is working perfectly and is logging everything as I want it. However, it can take hours to complete, and I noticed that if I open the excel file while it's still running, it fails and throws a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` exception with this message `(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)` when it tries to save to the file.

My guess is that by opening the excel file, the program is getting locked out of writing to it. How can I get around this? Is there a way to lock users out of opening the file while the program runs (Forcing them to access it as read-only)?

This is the code that gets used to initially create the file:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

//.. bunch of POI stuff here

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\ file path here");
wb.write(fileOut);
wb.close();
fileOut.close();
```

And then in a separate logResults() method, the file is accessed and saved:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\ file path here"));

HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

//.. bunch more POI stuff here

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\ file path here");
wb.write(fileOut);
wb.close();
fileOut.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do anything in Java side.

You may need do something in Excel file as follows

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly 
Then
MsgBox "File already in use"
ThisWorkbook.Close 
savechanges:=False
End If
End Sub
```

'This is workbook event code.
'To input this code, right click on the Excel icon on the worksheet
'(or next to the File menu if you maximise your workbooks),
'select View Code from the menu, and paste the code

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. I'm not sure if it's the most elegant solution, but it seems to work well enough.

When the file is created, I set it to read only with. Then every time I will log a result, I switch it back to writeable, and then back to read only after it's saved.

Basically something like this:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
//..

file.setWritable(true);
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
file.setReadOnly();
```